# How to remove the first 3 characters from all values in a column (SAS, SQL)

Tags: sql, sas, truncate

I have a variable that starts with OMX, but I only need the value that comes after it. How can I create a new variable that only has the value after OST;
Example: OSTN44X8 has to become N44X8 only

```
proc sql; 
(Select * 
From data01 
WHERE RDATE between '2000-11-01' and '2018-02-25' 
(SELECT SUBSTR(REP_ID,4) AS ID ) ; 
quit;
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Hint: SUBSTR().

Comment: See the function SUBSTR

Comment: @Reeza I tried the following, it runs but no variable is created: proc sql; (Select *
From data01
WHERE RDATE between '2000-11-01' and '2018-02-25' 
(SELECT SUBSTR(REP_ID,4) AS ID
) ; quit;     The variable I try to modify is rep_id and it should create a new column named ID where the value of rep_id starts from the 4th character

Comment: You really shouldn't add code to the comments, you can edit your question instead. Please do so in the future.

Comment: Sample data expected results added to question would help as well.  but substring, repalce conditional evaluations all things to consider

Answer (score 1):

You can combine len function and subtr function together to achive your result.

```
Substr(REP_ID,4,len(REP_ID)-4)
```

Answer (score 1):

all you need to add an alias for table when you want to mention *

> ```
> proc sql; 
>  Select a.*,
> SUBSTR(REP_ID,4) AS ID
> From data01 a
> WHERE RDATE between '2000-11-01' and '2018-02-25' 
> ; 
> quit;
> ```

Comment: The alias is not needed because in this case, all the variables are in the same one table : data01. I think krilee has to verify if the table is named really "data01" and if this table is in the "work" library. If it is not, he has to add the name of the library before, like : if the library is named "thelab" then use : From thelab.data01.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `IN:` operator to make sure you only substr the appropriate values.

Example:

Each when should have in: list of prefixes of same length you want to exclude.

```
, case 
    when rep_id in: ('OMX', 'OMT') then substrn(rep_id,4)
    when rep_id in: ('XYZZY')      then substrn(rep_id,6)
    otherwise rep_id
  end as id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SUBSTR to return the correct string. In SAS, the last parameter is optional and if you skip it, it retrieves from the start to the end automatically.

```
select substr(REP_ID, 4) as ID
```

If it's SQL your code would look something like that. Your SQL has several other errors but I'll leave those up to you to resolve.

If it's a data step use the following instead:

```
ID = substr(REP_ID, 4);
```

Comment: That is exactly what I did, but no new variable ID was generated. It is just the same table. What could be the problem?

Comment: Then you did something wrong. Post your full code and log.

Comment: I would make sure your SQL query was first working and then add that in as the last step, like I mentioned you had other SQL errors in your code that make it invalid, you need to fix those as well.

Answer (score 0):

do you mean :

```
proc sql; 
Select *,
SUBSTR(REP_ID,4) AS ID
From data01 
WHERE RDATE between '2000-11-01' and '2018-02-25' 
; 
quit;
```

?

Comment: When I do it your way I get the following error: "Syntax error: SELECT * must have a FROM clause" but I do have from clause included. So I really don't know what the issue is :(

Comment: do you want to create a table or not ? is the table data01 exists? where is it saved?

Comment: You probably need to qualify the asterisk: `Select data01.*, ...`